# Bullet physics Cylinder to Box collision

Tags: c++, bulletphysics

Based off of this [tutorial](http://www.bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Hello_World) I have added bullet physics into my opengl engine. Cylinders colliders collide with other cylinders perfectly, but they do not seem to collide with box colliders. Here is the code I used to setup my world:

```
btBroadphaseInterface* broadphase = new btDbvtBroadphase();
btDefaultCollisionConfiguration* collisionConfiguration = new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration();
btCollisionDispatcher* collisionDispatcher = new btCollisionDispatcher(collisionConfiguration);
btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver* collisionSolver = new btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver();
btDiscreteDynamicsWorld* dynamicsWorld = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(collisionDispatcher, broadphase, collisionSolver, collisionConfiguration);
dynamicsWorld->setGravity(btVector3(0, -10, 0));

// create collision shapes:
// the box is part of the terrain and cannot move, set mass to 0 for now
btCollisionShape* box = new btBoxShape(btVector3(box_length.x, box_length.y, box_length.z));
btDefaultMotionState* box_motion_state = new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), btVector3(box_position.x, box_position.y, box_position.z)));
btRigidBody* box_body = new btRigidBody(btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo(btScalar(0.0f), box_motion_state, box, btVector3(0, 0, 0)));
dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(box_body);

// the cylinder can move. Mass = 1.0 for now
btCollisionShape* cylinder = new btCylinderShape(btVector3(radius, height, radius));
btDefaultMotionState* cylinder_motion_state = new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), btVector3(cylinder_position.x, cylinder_position.y, cylinder_position.z)));
btRigidBody* cylinder_body = new btRigidBody(btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo(btScalar(1.0f), cylinder_motion_state, cylinder, btVector3(0, 0, 0)));
dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(cylinder_body);

// ... Carry out same process for every other shape in scene
```

I know that this code is making the shapes correctly as my btIDebugDraw class is rendering all the collision shapes perfectly. Once again cylinder to cylinder collisions are ok, but I cannot seem to get cylinder to box collisions to work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Turns out my z-length was negative. Using the absolute math function fixed it.